# create object prototype callable has object and function

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I'm trying to learn how to use protoyping in js.

**First problem:**

I want to do an function like `$()` in jQuery.
When I call it like this `Jo("header h1")`, it work, but not when i call `Jo.infos()`.

```
var Jo = function( selector ){

    return new Jo.init(selector);

};

Jo.prototype = {
    infos: function(){
        return "Hello! I'm Jo, I'm here to make your life easier";
    }
};

Jo.init = function( selector ){

    this.selector = selector;

};
```

Where is my error, how to fix it ?

**Second problem:**

The returned object is `Jo.init` but I want `Jo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly find my solution:

```
(function( window, undefined ){

    var Jo = function( selector, context ){
        return new Jo.fn.init(selector, context);
    };

    Jo.fn = Jo.prototype = {
        Jo: "0.1",
        constructor: Jo,
        init: function( selector, context ){

            console.log( "$() request work" );

        }
    };

    Jo.infos = function(){

        console.log("info work");

    };

    Jo.fn.init.prototype = Jo.fn;

    if( typeof window === "object" && typeof window.document === "object" ) window.Jo = window.$ = Jo;

})( window );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `__proto__` which is not standard.
Use this:

```
var Jo = function( selector ){
    this.init(selector);
};

Jo.prototype = {
    infos: function(){
        return "Hello! I'm Jo, I'm here to make your life easier";
    },
    init : function( selector ){
           this.selector = selector;
    },
    constructor : Jo //reset constructor, because we are using object literal which override the original prototype object
};
var jo = new Jo('jojo');
console.log(jo instanceof Jo); //return true
console.log(jo.infos());    //display the Hello....
```

In your code, the instance you created is an instance of Jo.init because you return an new object explicitly. So this instance doesn't have access to Jo's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `prototype` of your actual constructor, `Jo.init`, to the prototype object that you are going to use. Also, if you want to call `Jo.infos()` on the `Jo` function itself instead of on instances, you will have to place it there and not on the prototype.

```
function Jo(selector) {
    return new Jo.init(selector);
}
Jo.init = function(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
};
Jo.init.prototype = Jo.prototype = {
    // instance methods here
    …
}

Jo.infos = function(){
    return "Hello! I'm Jo, I'm here to make your life easier";
};
```

Without an extra `init` function:

```
function Jo(selector) {
    if (! (this instanceof Jo)) return new Jo(selector);

    this.selector = selector;
}
Jo.prototype = {
    // instance methods here
    …
}

Jo.infos = function(){
    return "Hello! I'm Jo, I'm here to make your life easier";
};
```

Answer (score -1):

`__proto__` is the object that is used in the lookup chain to resolve methods

`prototype` is the object that is used to build `__proto__` when you create an object with new

```
var Jo = function( selector ){
  return new Jo.init(selector);
};

Jo.__proto__= {                 //<---------------------  __proto__
  infos: function(){
      return "Hello! I'm Jo, I'm here to make your life easier";
  }
};

Jo.init = function( selector ){

  this.selector = selector;

};
```

Comment: Try `Jo instanceof Function`